# Foreign Key vs. Custom Field in Django

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm curious about convention in Django. I may be completely off track here but it seems to me that ForeignKey can often replace the need of defining your own custom Field in Django.

For example this is what my code looks like now,

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    object_type = models.ForeignKey(Object_Type)


class Object_Type(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Could this not be replaced with something like this?

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    object_type = models.CustomField()
```

Where the custom field is a field I've defined that covers all the, say, 10 types of 
objects I could possibly have. 
What is the best way between these two?

Comment: For this example, i would recommend the `ForeignKey` approach, as you have everything laid out for you.

Comment: Assuming I do it this way... Since I know I only have 10 object_types would I just pre-populate the database with those ten values and not let users add/remove from that table? What is the best way to do this and would a customField allow me NOT to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement a `ForeignKey` as your own `CustomField`.  It would not be in the Django `models` (that is, you couldn't use `models.CustomField()`).  You would use your own class name instead, and it would [subclass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) `models.Field`

It's not clear how you would handle mixed types (like int, float, etc.).  You would need to convert them to a shared representation, like a string.

Another option is to declare the object class and query the appropriate model.  For example, if you had:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    object_class = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Object20(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

then you could write:

```
m = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
if m.object_class == 'Object20':
    o = Object20.objects.filter(mymodel=m).get()
    value = o.value
```

Django provides a [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) but I don't recommend it.  A single request can lock up multiple database tables.  However, it solves the problem you are describing.